# CakePHP views part

Tags: cakephp

I am having a problem in my CakePHP application. I want to retrieve the values from the Table named choices I am retrieving it correctly. The values are coming correctly in the controller part. But in my view part it's showing only the last values retrieved...

My code is:

```
function view($formid = null,$userid=null)//viewPage
        {
         $this->set('Forms',$this->Form->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('Form.id'=>$formid),'fields'=>array('Form.name'))));
         $this->data['Form']['id']=$formid;
         $viewfields=$this->Form->viewForms($this->data);
         $this->set('viewfields',$viewfields);//retreives all the Attributes from the Form (like attribute_id,,label)

            foreach($viewfields as $attributeid)://For each attribute id , i am checking if there is any choices in the Table Choices
                    $choices=$this->Choice->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('Choice.attribute_id'=>$attributeid['Attribute']['id'],'Choice.label'=>$attributeid['Attribute']['label']),'fields'=>array('Choice.choice','Choice.label')));

                 if(!empty($choices)){
               $this->set('options',$choices);

                             foreach($choices as $c):
                                     echo $c['Choice']['label'];
                                     echo $c['Choice']['choice'];

                              endforeach;
                         }

             endforeach;
        }
```

The above works well in the Controller part, but if I use:

```
                         foreach($options as $c):
                                 echo $c['Choice']['label'];
                 echo $c['Choice']['choice'];

                          endforeach;
```

Only the last values are shown... Why is this so?
Eg. my attributes table contains entries like:

```
      id form_id label type sequence_no
       1  1        Name  text  1
       2  1        age   number 2
       3  1       gender  dropdown 3
       4  1       email-id email   4
       5   1      qualification dropdown 5
```

In my choices table:

```
     id attribute_id  label choice  sequence
      1  3             gender male    1
      2  3             gender female   2
      3  5            qualification BE 1
      4  5             qualification ME 2
      5  5             qualification MBA 3
```

In the `view.ctp` I am getting only the entries for qualification. Why is this so?

Edit:

My view page is like:

```
    <?php foreach ($viewfields as $r): ?>
     if($r['Attribute']['type']=='text'||$r['Attribute']['type']=="email"){
echo $form->input($r['Attribute']['label'], array('id'=>$r['Attribute']['id'],'name'=>$r['Attribute']['label'],'type'=>'text','style' => 'width:' . $r['Attribute']['size'] . 'px'));
?><br>
}

     else if($r['Attribute']['type']=='dropdown')
                                {
//here i want the Male and female for the label gender and for the label Qualification as BE ME MBA


 echo $form->input($r['Attribute']['label'], array('id'=>$r['Attribute']['id'],'name'=>$r['Attribute']['label'],'options' => array(1,2,3,4,5)));

       }
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

for a sample I have used `12345` as options ..

within that `elseif(dropdown)` loop I have tried the options as you said like

```
     foreach($options as $c):

                                                    echo $c['Choice']['label'];
                                                 echo $c['Choice']['choice'];
                                                     echo $c[1]['Choice']['label'];
                                                     echo $c[1]['Choice']['choice'];
                                                   endforeach;
```

But I'm getting errors and also the whole array is displayed but I want only the gender options for the label gender and qualification options for the qualifications.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to add attribute_id as key of $choices,

```
foreach($viewfields as $attributeid)://For each attribute id , i am checking if there is any choices in the Table Choices
             $choices[$attributeid['Attribute']['id']]=$this->Choice->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('Choice.attribute_id'=>$attributeid['Attribute']['id'],'Choice.label'=>$attributeid['Attribute']['label']),'fields'=>array('Choice.choice','Choice.label')));
             $this->set('options',$choices);
endforeach;
```

And in view you can manipulate this array by........... [Check your view.ctp code given here.. place this instead of array(1,2,3,4,5)]

```
 echo $form->input($r['Attribute']['label'], array('id'=>$r['Attribute']['id'],'name'=>$r['Attribute']['label'],'options' => $options[$r['Attribute']['id']]));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->set('options', $choices);
```

This will set a variable called `$options` in your view that contains `$choices`. You can not set this variable several times, there can only be one `$options` in your view. You're overwriting the same variable several times, so only the last time it sticks. What you want is something more akin to:

```
$options = array();
foreach (...) {
    ...
    $options[] = $results;
}
$this->set('options', $options);
```

But I think your code could use a lot more improvements. Fetching results several times from the database in a `foreach` loop is not a good idea.